# when converting to csv from python i a missing first column in excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

i had header info like

```
header = Sr. No.^Name of Deductor^TAN of Deductor^^^^^Total Amount Paid / Credited(Rs.)^Total Tax Deducted(Rs.)^Total TDS Deposited(Rs.)^Sr. No.^Section^Transaction Date^Status of Booking^Date of Booking^Remarks^Amount Paid / Credited(Rs.)^Tax Deducted(Rs.)^TDS Deposited(Rs.)
```

converting in to csv like

```
flat_text = ''.join(header) # flatten list to string        
dfs[name] = pd.read_csv(StringIO(flat_text), sep="^")
dfs["PART A"].to_csv("f.csv")
```

Then I am getting a excel where all the data in header arranged in excel from column B and column A is empty. Why I am missing data to start from Column A?

Answer (score 0):

The first column contains the index labels, which you can suppress like this:

```
dfs["PART A"].to_csv("f.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: when i gave this header information comes to Column A that is satisfying but the values for headers are getting missed for first column,
```
Ex-Data 
 sr.no   Name  marks
1          AKhil    50
when using index= False it was going like
 sr.no   Name  marks
 AKhil    50
```
Serial No values are missing.